# PHP If blocks only uses the last block

Tags: php, if-statement, statements

I have code that looks like this:

```
if ($first == 1); {
$q1 = "1";
$q2 = "2";
$q3 = "3";
}

if ($first == 2); {
$q1 = "1a";
$q2 = "2a";
$q3 = "3a";
}

if ($first == 3); {
$q1 = "1b";
$q2 = "2b";
$q3 = "3b";
}
```

The variable $first comes out of an array that was sorted earlier. It's a key value from that array.

In this case, the variable is 2, yet the code -always- takes the last block regardless of anything else. So it would report the answers for the 3 block, not the 2 block.

That is to say, getting a value of 1, 2 or 3 for $first will always return 1b for $q1.

Anyone know why? this is making me go insane.

Answer (score 4):

First, remove the semicolons from the brackets surrounding your conditions.

Secondly, you should use `if()` and `else if()`:

```
if($first == 1) {
    $q1 = "1";
    $q2 = "2";
    $q3 = "3";
} else if($first == 2) {
    $q1 = "1a";
    $q2 = "2a";
    $q3 = "3a";
} else if($first == 3) {
    $q1 = "1b";
    $q2 = "2b";
    $q3 = "3b";
}
```

If you're comparing more than 3 states, however, you should use a `switch()` statement to produce cleaner code, like this:

```
switch($first) {
    case 1:
        $q1 = "1";
        $q2 = "2";
        $q3 = "3";
    break;
    case 2:
        $q1 = "1a";
        $q2 = "2a";
        $q3 = "3a";
    break;
    case 3:
        $q1 = "1b";
        $q2 = "2b";
        $q3 = "3b";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Or just use a switch statement.

Comment: @C0deH4cker In this case, using an `if()` is fine. A `switch()` would incur more lines of code, but I agree if more than 3 states are being tested, a switch is the best way to go.

Comment: I used to write a switch when I've got more than 2 states, that's clearer, even id there are a bit more line. But this is a personnal choice.

Comment: Boooo. :) The downside to using `switch` is that it's so easy to forget the `break` statements.  For that reason, I prefer `if/else`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have `;` on the end of your if statments. I.e change `if ($first == 1); {` to this `if ($first == 1) {`

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a switch statement :

```
switch($first) 
{
    case 1:
       $q1 = "1";
       $q2 = "2";
       $q3 = "3";
       break;
    case 2:
       $q1 = "1a";
       $q2 = "2a";
       $q3 = "3a";
       break;
    case 3:
       $q1 = "1b";
       $q2 = "2b";
       $q3 = "3b";
       break;
    default:
}
```